# Disable text boxes in a loop using jquery when a particular radio box is selected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

In the below form, I want the text box to be enabled only when the radio button is checked. 
I have around 50 questions like this. for each question only YES is selectiod the text box should be enabled. otherwise not.

I don't want to do manual disable by calling with radio button's name, every time. But i want to do it in a loop as all the names have the names - ansr+qno. But i am unable to do it. Please help. Any other suggestions also appreciated.

```
<form id="sform" name="sform" method="post" action="processsurvey.php">

  <div class="qpanel">
    <div class="que"> <?php echo ++$qid ?> Content for  class "que" Goes Here </div>
    <div class="ans"> <input name="ansr2" type="radio" value="no" /> No </div>
    <div class="ans"> <input name="ansr2" type="radio" value="no" /> Yes 
    <input name="ansr2" type="text" placeholder="If any, give your answer here" /></div>
  </div>

  <div class="qpanel">
    <div class="que"> <?php echo ++$qid ?> Content for  class "que" Goes Here </div>
    <div class="ans"> <input name="ansr3" type="radio" value="no" /> No </div>
    <div class="ans"> <input name="ansr3" type="radio" value="no" /> Yes 
    <input name="ansr3" type="text" placeholder="If any, give your answer here" /></div>
  </div>


  <div class="finishpanel" align="center" >
  <input class="btn" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
  </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This task doesn't require a loop :

```
$('.qpanel :radio').change(function () {
    // closest : up to .qpanel
    // find : down to the textbox
    var textbox = $(this).closest('.qpanel').find(':text');
    switch ($(this).val()) {
        case 'no': textbox.prop('disabled', true); break;
        case 'yes': textbox.prop('disabled', false); break;
    }
});
```

Note that both values are currently set to "no" :

```
value="no" /> No
value="no" /> Yes
```

Here is a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/wared/TLgsb/.

Comment: Oh.. Ya!! Thanks alott..

Answer (score 0):

On each set your radio buttons both have `value="no"`? You should change that!

You can disable/enable input using `prop('disabled')`, passing `true` will disable the input and `false` will reenable it. Then set it on radios `change()` event.

This should do:

```
$('.qpanel').each(function(){
    var $qpanel = $(this);
    $qpanel.find('[type="radio"]').change(function(){         
        if($(this).val() == 'yes'){
            $qpanel.find('[type="text"]').prop('disabled', false);
        }else{
            $qpanel.find('[type="text"]').prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
});
```

See this [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/r8qv6/)